# play audio file at time defined wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio

I want to play an audio file from my isolated storage.. but I don't want to play from the beginning.. I want to play the audio file at 33seconds position.. How can I do this? Any function to define?

I have this method to open:

```
private void Play_Audio(string name_file)
    {


        using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (isf.FileExists(name_file))
            {
                using (var isoStream = isf.OpenFile(name_file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {

                    mediaSound.SetSource(isoStream);

                    mediaSound.Volume = 100;


                    mediaSound.Play();
                    mediaSound.Stop();
                    isoStream.Close();

                }
            }
            else
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("The file does not exist");
            }
        }

    }
```

There's nothing like mediaSound.PlayAtPosition(33)??????????

Show me an example;)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position to play at using the [`Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.position%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) property.

Please note that not all sources support being able to be played at a specific point so make sure you check support for this feature using the [`CanSeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.canseek%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) property.